# Последовательность синхронных запросов Retrofit2 для android

Tags: android, retrofit2

Какой подход лучше всего использовать, если необходимо выполнить несколько синхронных запросов подряд (после получения ответа от сервера слать следующий запрос и т.д.)? Причём выполнение этих запросов необходимо начать при наступлении какого-либо события, например, нажатия на кнопку или получении `Intent`'а.
Что лучше всего использовать: `Service`, либо связку `Thread`-`Looper`-`Handler`, либо что-то другое?

Comment: идеально - RxJava :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два самых простейших способа реализовать такое:
1) RxJava + Retrofit
2) LiveData + Transformations (Android Architecture components) + [LiveDataCallAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataCallAdapter.java) для Retrofit